# its possible css selector inside another selector

Tags: css, selector

sorry but it's confusing to me, somebody knows how it's possible or it's not possible..

```
#divp {
   background-color: lightgrey;
  .odiv {
      background-color: yellow;
      .pp  { background-color: black;   }
      a { color:red; }
   }
   .pp { background-color: lightgreen;  }
   a { color:blue; }
}

#divw {
   background-color: lightblue;
  .odiv {
      background-color: blue;
      .pp  { background-color: white;   }
      a { color:yellow; }
   }
   .pp { background-color: green;  }
   a { color:lightblue; }
}
```

i want create divs with internal css rules and i dont want to write all the time the same..... like

```
#diw .odiv .pp { background-color: white }
#diw .odiv .a { color: white }
#diw .odiv .other { color: blue }
```

is it possible?

Comment: You have to look al LESS or SASS. It is not possible with CSS alone.

Comment: You could use CSS preprocessors such as *less*, *Sass*, *Stylus*, ... to nest the selectors.

Answer (score 3):

Nesting selectors is not possible, but you might want to checkout CSS preprocessors, which will let you do this. http://lesscss.org/ for example.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible in standard CSS. But it is possible in Sass (and other CSS Preprocessors): http://sass-lang.com/guide#3

It works exactly as you posted in your question:

```
.div1{
  background-color: red;
  p{ font-size: 18px; }
}
```

Will output this:

```
.div1{ background-color: red }
.div1 p{ font-size: 18px; }
```

Check out http://sassmeister.com/ for a way to play around with Sass.